# Getting netflix to work with pipelight

Tags: netflix, pipelight

I installed and enabled silverlight with pipelight and changed my user agent to Windows Firefox but Netflix tells me I need to install silverlight. Additionally, the bubble demo for pipelight didn't work (it just gave me a button to instal silverlight). I am using the chrome browser (not chromium). Here is the output of `pipelight-plugin --system-check`

```
>> 32 bit <<
wine-1.7.20

Patches:
1b7ac850-5040-4d9e-8fde-9c483c3baf33:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Add commandline option --patches to show the patch list.
9e9a58e1-b226-4d4d-943b-be9a4c1dc525:1 :: Michael Müller :: Add commandline option --check-libs to test if shared libraries are installed.
8a366b6d-8ad6-4581-8aa9-66a03590a57b:2 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Implement SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE.
92938b89-506b-430a-ba50-32de8b286e56:6 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Store and return security attributes with extended file attributes.
5d6bb7b5-ec88-4ed3-907d-9ad2173a2f88:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Enable/disable windows when they are (un)mapped by foreign applications.
94186fff-6dbf-44d0-8eb1-2463d1608a0f:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Update gl_drawable for embedded windows.
cbe240e8-2c58-430a-b61c-7fbb9d0e1e11:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Change return value of stub SetNamedPipeHandleState to TRUE.
00273da7-72f8-4025-9e96-0c2bc95dacdb:3 :: Maarten Lankhorst :: Winepulse patches extracted from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/+files/wine1.7_1.7.19-0ubuntu2~trusty2.debian.tar.gz.
fbea4ef6-85ac-4524-b32d-fc9882b73e5a:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Implement GetVolumePathName.
4cd13e94-7f2d-11e3-b5eb-0090f5c75ad5:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Support for junction points/reparse points.
5fb1f5c8-7f17-11e3-9b62-0090f5c75ad5:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Implement TransmitFile.
3d7c4774-9e7f-11e3-9cfc-0090f5c75ad5:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Implement missing fonts expected by Silverlight.
e7581ed7-12b3-4ed3-835b-5a62afbf9c85:4 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Use lockfree implementation for get_cached_fd.
3405aa34-f341-11e3-83ce-0090f5c75ad5:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Add default security descriptor ownership and DACLs for processes.
d85bf5ee-3578-4edd-be3e-35cacd53e5cc:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Raise DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C exception in OutputDebugStringA.
0b21d7ac-0387-4493-aa38-fbafe3e749f5:2 :: Michael Müller :: Decrease minimum SetTimer interval to 5 ms.
2394843e-2bc4-4fa4-8368-1ef32093b89e:1 :: Michael Müller :: Allow changing strict draw ordering through an exported function.
255473fa-4e0a-4f51-952b-4deecc1a2181:1 :: Michael Müller :: Indicate direct rendering through OpenGL extension.
59bd38b7-bbdc-4cfd-9ccd-1c72c4ed84c0:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Implement X11DRV_FLUSH_GDI_DISPLAY ExtEscape command.
325645ba-d39d-4de4-9c94-3fe694eedaab:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: kernel32: Silence repeated CompareStringEx FIXME.
46fb5f97-34cb-4b6b-ae10-7511db90ba1d:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Avoid race-condition when unloading modules while hook is still active.
acff3012-0f75-4710-9941-08b5ce4c61f3:2 :: Erich E. Hoover :: wined3d: Silence repeated resource_check_usage FIXME.
c7263660-be78-439b-979f-e745a8d87120:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: wined3d: Silence repeated wined3d_swapchain_present FIXME.
eec5dea8-879d-417b-9f97-364deaae6576:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Add tests for IVMRMonitorConfig.
e46b26df-3c1b-419c-9579-f0d1e1c50bea:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Workaround for broken implementation of shlwapi url functions.

wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe"
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (2)
Checking OpenGL ...
OpenGL Vendor: nouveau
OpenGL Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on NVC1
OpenGL Direct Rendering: True
OpenGL: PASSED

Checking fonts ...
Found Arial in Z:\opt\wine-compholio\bin\..\share\wine\fonts\\arial.ttf
Missing Verdana
Fonts: FAILURE

Checking ACLs / XATTR ...
ACLs: PASSED

Checking libraries...
libcapi20.so.3: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcapi20.so.3
libcups.so.2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2
libdbus-1.so.3: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
libfontconfig.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
libGL.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgnutls.so.26: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26
libgsm.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1
libjpeg.so.8: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libncurses.so.5: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
libnetapi.so: missing
libodbc.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1
libpng12.so.0: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libsane.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsane.so.1
libtiff.so.5: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5
libv4l1.so.0: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0
libXcomposite.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1
libXcursor.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1
libXext.so.6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6
libXi.so.6: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6
libXinerama.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1
libXrandr.so.2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2
libXrender.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1
libxslt.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1
libXxf86vm.so.1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1
Libraries: FAILURE

>> 64 bit <<
wine-1.7.20

Patches:
1b7ac850-5040-4d9e-8fde-9c483c3baf33:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Add commandline option --patches to show the patch list.
9e9a58e1-b226-4d4d-943b-be9a4c1dc525:1 :: Michael Müller :: Add commandline option --check-libs to test if shared libraries are installed.
8a366b6d-8ad6-4581-8aa9-66a03590a57b:2 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Implement SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE.
92938b89-506b-430a-ba50-32de8b286e56:6 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Store and return security attributes with extended file attributes.
5d6bb7b5-ec88-4ed3-907d-9ad2173a2f88:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Enable/disable windows when they are (un)mapped by foreign applications.
94186fff-6dbf-44d0-8eb1-2463d1608a0f:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Update gl_drawable for embedded windows.
cbe240e8-2c58-430a-b61c-7fbb9d0e1e11:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Change return value of stub SetNamedPipeHandleState to TRUE.
00273da7-72f8-4025-9e96-0c2bc95dacdb:3 :: Maarten Lankhorst :: Winepulse patches extracted from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/+files/wine1.7_1.7.19-0ubuntu2~trusty2.debian.tar.gz.
fbea4ef6-85ac-4524-b32d-fc9882b73e5a:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Implement GetVolumePathName.
4cd13e94-7f2d-11e3-b5eb-0090f5c75ad5:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Support for junction points/reparse points.
5fb1f5c8-7f17-11e3-9b62-0090f5c75ad5:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Implement TransmitFile.
3d7c4774-9e7f-11e3-9cfc-0090f5c75ad5:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Implement missing fonts expected by Silverlight.
e7581ed7-12b3-4ed3-835b-5a62afbf9c85:4 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Use lockfree implementation for get_cached_fd.
3405aa34-f341-11e3-83ce-0090f5c75ad5:1 :: Erich E. Hoover :: Add default security descriptor ownership and DACLs for processes.
d85bf5ee-3578-4edd-be3e-35cacd53e5cc:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Raise DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C exception in OutputDebugStringA.
0b21d7ac-0387-4493-aa38-fbafe3e749f5:2 :: Michael Müller :: Decrease minimum SetTimer interval to 5 ms.
2394843e-2bc4-4fa4-8368-1ef32093b89e:1 :: Michael Müller :: Allow changing strict draw ordering through an exported function.
255473fa-4e0a-4f51-952b-4deecc1a2181:1 :: Michael Müller :: Indicate direct rendering through OpenGL extension.
59bd38b7-bbdc-4cfd-9ccd-1c72c4ed84c0:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Implement X11DRV_FLUSH_GDI_DISPLAY ExtEscape command.
325645ba-d39d-4de4-9c94-3fe694eedaab:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: kernel32: Silence repeated CompareStringEx FIXME.
46fb5f97-34cb-4b6b-ae10-7511db90ba1d:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Avoid race-condition when unloading modules while hook is still active.
acff3012-0f75-4710-9941-08b5ce4c61f3:2 :: Erich E. Hoover :: wined3d: Silence repeated resource_check_usage FIXME.
c7263660-be78-439b-979f-e745a8d87120:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: wined3d: Silence repeated wined3d_swapchain_present FIXME.
eec5dea8-879d-417b-9f97-364deaae6576:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Add tests for IVMRMonitorConfig.
e46b26df-3c1b-419c-9579-f0d1e1c50bea:1 :: Sebastian Lackner :: Workaround for broken implementation of shlwapi url functions.

wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe"
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (2)
Checking OpenGL ...
OpenGL Vendor: nouveau
OpenGL Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on NVC1
OpenGL Direct Rendering: True
OpenGL: PASSED

Checking fonts ...
Found Arial in Z:\opt\wine-compholio\bin\..\share\wine\fonts\\arial.ttf
Missing Verdana
Fonts: FAILURE

Checking ACLs / XATTR ...
ACLs: PASSED

Checking libraries...
libcapi20.so.3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcapi20.so.3
libcups.so.2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2
libdbus-1.so.3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
libfontconfig.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
libGL.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
libgnutls.so.26: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26
libgsm.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1
libjpeg.so.8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libncurses.so.5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
libnetapi.so: missing
libodbc.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1
libpng12.so.0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libsane.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsane.so.1
libtiff.so.5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5
libv4l1.so.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0
libXcomposite.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1
libXcursor.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1
libXext.so.6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6
libXi.so.6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6
libXinerama.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1
libXrandr.so.2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2
libXrender.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1
libxslt.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1
libXxf86vm.so.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1
Libraries: FAILURE
```

How do I get it working?

Thanks,

Ren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem, but I'm running Netflix in Firefox (which may be a better option altogether it seems), and have tried a few more things to fix it. Looking at the output of your diagnostic, it looks like you're missing the ms core fonts package, which you can install by using the following instructions:

https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight/+faq/2441

Hope this helps. Bear in mind that you might need to install the Agent Overrider Firefox add-on for Firefox to use Netflix.